# 3g modem SIM failure

Tags: modem, 3g, hyperterminal, sim

Recently bought Huawei e226 unlocked. Sucessfully connected to PC.

```
Manufacturer: huawei
Model: E226
Revision: 11.310.16.02.133
IMEI: 357650*********
+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES
```

Inserted SIM card and tried to get some carrier info, but got this:

```
AT+CIMI
+CME ERROR: SIM failure
```

Tried several SIM cards with no effect. Device seems to be not locked.

```
AT^CARDLOCK?
^CARDLOCK: 2,10,0
```

Are there any ways to disgnose possible issues ?

Comment: I assume these SIM cards are known to be good?

Comment: correct, I used nanoSIM with adapter, but I think it doesn't matter

Comment: Have you solved this?  If not, have you checked to see if there is a firmware upgrade that fixes the problem?

Comment: Or maybe it is a problem with the SIM contacts.

Comment: I've found that Huawei USB modems don't like to have the sim card inserted after boot. Try inserting the SIM before powering up the modem. If you can't for whatever reason, issue an AT^RESET after inserting the modem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer, but here's what helped me with Huawei E1550.

I inserted the problematic SIM card into a normal smartphone and waited for it to get the signal. It showed me "No SIM card" at first, then "No signal". I had to try several times and at last it showed me the carrier name. Once I put it back into the modem, it worked.

Few clarifications:

- this was in an area with stable and good reception
- this SIM card wasn't used for a few months
- `picocom` helped me issue commands and immediately see the modem's response
- [see this for more information](http://mebubo.github.io/2011/10/13/using-huawei-e1550-3g-modem-in-debian.html)

I am still not sure what was that, but this may save whoever finds this some time on not having to Google further.